# djangoTypeError at /accounts/signout/ unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, django, dictionary

i am very new in django.i am developing a web app where i have used userena.I am facing error while i have tried to pass a dictionary in the **signout** view of userena.This is the error,

```
TypeError at /accounts/signout/
unhashable type: 'dict'
```

**views.py**

```
@secure_required
def signout(request, next_page=userena_settings.USERENA_REDIRECT_ON_SIGNOUT,
        template_name='userena/home_index.html', *args, **kwargs):

   latest_images = Photo.objects.order_by('-uploaded_time')[:20]
   ctx = {'images':latest_images}
   context = RequestContext(request)
   if request.user.is_authenticated() and userena_settings.USERENA_USE_MESSAGES: # pragma: no cover
       messages.success(request, _('You have been signed out.'), fail_silently=True)
   userena_signals.account_signout.send(sender=None, user=request.user)
   return Signout(request,ctx,next_page, template_name, *args, **kwargs,context)
```

i said that i am a novice in Django, so for sure i am doing wrong here.Now my question is how do i pass a dictionary with  userena signout view.In mention,i need to pass that dictionary and  use it in the given template.

Comment: What does your `Signout` function returns because `signout` must return a HttpResponse object.

Comment: return `Signout(request)` is by default Redirect to a success page,and the success page has been defined in the `def signout()` as a parameter,you can see in my above given code.in mention `Signout(request)` is the default function of django imported from `django.auth.contrib`

Answer (score 0):

In Django, the context is the place where you put the stuff you want to use in the templates. If I understood what you are trying to do, I think you should do this:

```
context = RequestContext(request, ctx)
```